# arrow keys stop working to scroll pages

Tags: firefox, accessibility, scrolling

Sometimes, the arrow keys stop working to scroll pages. Sometimes, in Firefox -> Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Accessibility -> General, the first checkbox, about using arrow keys to scroll pages, appears checked and some other times, unchecked. When it's unchecked, I check it. When it's checked, I keep it checked. In both times, I click OK. Then, the arrow keys restart working to scroll pages. I'm having to do it all the time. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.....[F7 fixed it :)](http://www.mozilla.org/access/features)

> Browse with caret allows users to
>   select arbitrary content with the
>   keyboard and move through content as
>   if inside a read-only editor. This
>   allows copying arbitrary pieces of
>   text to the clipboard. **The F7 key
>   toggles this feature on/off.**