# Scroll with arrow keys not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, google-chrome-extensions, scrolling

Since last night i am having trouble browsing any websites using arrow keys. When i want to scroll up/down a blinking cursor appears from no-where similar to word docs that lets cursors select text and scroll up/down when cursor/keyboard-focus reaches to its end point. I deactivated all extensions and updated chrome but it simply doesn't go away. Very annoying as it slows down my work. My screenshot below. You can see the cursor/keyboard-focus there as if i pressed the tab button. I must have accidentally pressed some key and it got activated. I have no clue. I am on Windows 7.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J80Xs.jpg

Answer (score 9):

Shortly after posting this question i found another post [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/97090/arrow-keys-stop-working-to-scroll-pages) for firefox and that did the trick. The F7 key was the reason. I pressed it again and things got back to normal.

Comment: Confirmed working w/ Chrome version 88.0. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: This is referred as "caret browsing"